# How to change value of "disableSelection" of a grid in Ext js 4.0 dynamically?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have the grid coded in Ext js 4.0. Below is the code:

```
    var xxx=Ext.create('Ext.grid.GridPanel', {
                    title: 'tableId',
                    id : 'tableId',
                    disableSelection:true,

                    //remaining code

            }
```

I want to change the value of **"disableSelection"** **dynamically** outside the grid according to **two different conditions**.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to disable selection of the grid rows (such as in a checkbox selection model) you can use:

```
xxx.getSelectionModel().setLocked(true);
```

To enable selection just use the reverse:

```
xxx.getSelectionModel().setLocked(false);
```

Please see this fiddle for an example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nf8

Comment: Nice solution. I was trying to find something like this in documentation.

Comment: Note that [`setLocked`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-setLocked) will just lock the current selection state, i.e. prevent any changes on the selection. If you really want to **disable** selection, you should also call [`deselectAll`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-deselectAll) prior to locking the selection model.